# how to return the version of my current bower package with javascript?

Tags: javascript, bower

I would like to return with a method the bower.json version. like a

```
function getVersion(){
    return bower.version;
};
```

Using bower and using node;

Answer (score 0):

For example like this:

```
var bower = require('./bower.json');

console.log(bower.version);
```

Comment: mmmm it doesn't work: It says Cannot find module './bower.json'

Comment: As bower.json is a json file you will need to parse it to read the version field  as it will not be available as a module.

Comment: @JoséManuelBerrettaMoreno `./bower.json` is a relative path(this one means that `bower.json` and your `*.js` file are in the same folder)



@markyph you don't have to parse it - https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/commit/588d885e81dec667920383ac7246daceeb7f99fd